# Drawing basic shapes in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, geometry

How would I draw a simple partially transparent rectangle in python. I would like to not download anything from the internet and purely use python 2.7.3. I would like to also control where the rectangle starts and ends and control its width and height. The end goal of this is to have a map (of michigan and its great lakes) and have color coded rectangles pop up along the coast to visually show what the expected weather will be like based of buoys data from the NDBV. So in short, a map that i can place color coded rectangles on, that will be oriented along the coast of western michigan.

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Are you trying to generate a bitmap image (ie .jpg or .png) or vector graphics (ie .svg) or some sort of interactive user interface (ie tkinter or turtle graphics)?

Comment: Try the [tKinter](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/tkinter.html#module-Tkinter) module.

Comment: I was hoping to generate a map of Michigan and then be able to place colored rectangles on the map. I'm not sure what the type of formate this would be generating, but i know in my physics class we did all this through an output window, and that seemed like the easiest thing.

Comment: @LouisMarr: what is the final purpose of the map - is it to be real-time output for your program, or to be saved to go in a web page, or to be printed out? Do you want to place rectangles interactively (ie by hand), or have them automatically placed by your program? Do you already have a map, as an image or as vector data? How firmly are you set against installing modules (matplotlib has some map add-ins which might be very helpful here)?

Comment: The final goal is to use buoy data to predict the weather along the coast of michigan. Now the goal in setting up this map with rectangles over it is to have the user input a value which will be hours from the current time to see what the weather will be like along the coasts of michigan. So i have a map that that I would like to have put up next to the input box and button that shows the current/future weather along coastal areas using a color coated rectangles. So they would only have to pop up once but their color would need to be variable.

Comment: Im currently looking at using tkinter so that I can set up the text box and button to a frame on the left and then have the map appear as a frame on the right. I was then going to try to figure out how to create rectangles/line segments/circles in tkinter and use the .place() function to put them over the map in their respective places. Does this sound like a okay plan or are their serious flaws in it that i have yet to see. I have found out how to upload image but i have yet to figure out how to add the rectangles in the manner that I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some Tkinter sample code. Note that, so far as I am aware, Tkinter does not support transparency; but it can fake it by stippling, as demonstrated here:

```
# copied from http://www.kosbie.net/cmu/fall-10/15-110/koz/misc-demos/src/semi-transparent-stipple-demo.py

# semi-transparent-stipple-demo.py
# note: stipple only works for some objects (like rectangles)
# and not others (like ovals).  But it's better than nothing...

from Tkinter import *

def redrawAll(canvas):
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    # draw a red rectangle on the left half
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 250, 600, fill="red")
    # draw semi-transparent rectangles in the middle
    canvas.create_rectangle(200,  75, 300, 125, fill="blue", stipple="")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 175, 300, 225, fill="blue", stipple="gray75")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 275, 300, 325, fill="blue", stipple="gray50")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 375, 300, 425, fill="blue", stipple="gray25")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 475, 300, 525, fill="blue", stipple="gray12")

def init(canvas):
    redrawAll(canvas)

########### copy-paste below here ###########

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    # Store canvas in root and in canvas itself for callbacks
    root.canvas = canvas.canvas = canvas
    # Set up canvas data and call init
    canvas.data = { }
    init(canvas)
    # set up events
    # root.bind("<Button-1>", mousePressed)
    # root.bind("<Key>", keyPressed)
    # timerFired(canvas)
    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()  # This call BLOCKS (so your program waits until you close the window!)

run()
```

which produces something like

[image]

Comment: Thats fantastic but is there a way to change the orientation of the rectangle. So that it is oriented at different angles?

Comment: You would have to find the corner points and draw it as a Polygon, not a Rectangle (Tkinter rectangles are only axis-aligned).

Answer (score 0):

Check out

svgfig or svgwrite for svg

reportlab for pdf

pyglet for drawing to a window