# Overlaying a box on label image using Tkinter

Tags: image, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I am using Tkinter and the `grid()` layout manager to create a GUI.  I am showing the image in my GUI using a label, on a tabbed window:

```
label2 = ttk.Label(tab2)
image2 = PhotoImage(file="lizard.gif")
label2['image'] = image2
label2.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)
```

For illustration, let's say the image is 300 x 900.  If I know a set of coordinates within the image, how can I overlay a shaded box on the image, defined by the known (A,B,C,D which are shown just for the illustration purpose) coordinates?

[image: Illustration of concept]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you a step by step solution.

You can use a `tkinter.Label()` to display your image as you did, you can also choose other widgets. But for situation, let's choose `tkinter.Canvas()` widget instead (but same reasoning is valid if you choose to use `tkinter.Label()`)

## Technical issues:

Your problem contains 2 main sub-problems to resolve:

- How to overlay 2 images the way you want.
- How to display an image using `tkinter.Canvas()`

To be able to read an image of *jpg* format , you need to use a specific [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (or its [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) fork) method and a class:

- [`PIL.Image.open()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#open-rotate-and-display-an-image-using-the-default-viewer)
- [`PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html)

This is done by 3 lines in the below program:

```
self.im = Image.open(self.saved_image)
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
```

And then display `self.photo` in the `self.canvas` widget we opted for:

```
self.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=tk.N+tk.W, image = self.photo)
```

Second, to reproduce the effect you desire, use [`cv2.addWeighted()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) OpenCV method. But I feel you have already done that. So I just show you the portion of code of the program that does it:

```
self.img = cv2.imread(self.image_to_read)
self.overlay = self.img.copy()
cv2.rectangle(self.overlay, (500,50), (400,100), (0, 255, 0), -1)
self.opacity = 0.4
cv2.addWeighted(self.overlay, self.opacity, self.img, 1 - self.opacity, 0, self.img)
cv2.imwrite( self.saved_image, self.img)
```

## Program design:

I use 2 methods:
 - `__init__()`: Prepare the frame and call the GUI initialization method.
 - `initialize_user_interface()`: Draw the GUI and perform the previous operations.

But for [scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) reasons, it is better to create a separate method to handle the different operations of the image.

## Full program (OpenCV + tkinter)

Here is the source code (I used Python 3.4):

```
'''
Created on Apr 05, 2016

@author: Bill Begueradj
'''
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PIL



class Begueradj(tk.Frame):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''


    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Prepare the frame and call the GUI initialization method.
        '''
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """Draw a user interface allowing the user to type        
        """
        self.parent.title("Bill BEGUERADJ: Image overlay with OpenCV + Tkinter")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.image_to_read = 'begueradj.jpg'      
        self.saved_image = 'bill_begueradj.jpg'

        self.img = cv2.imread(self.image_to_read)
        self.overlay = self.img.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(self.overlay, (500,50), (400,100), (0, 255, 0), -1)
        self.opacity = 0.4
        cv2.addWeighted(self.overlay, self.opacity, self.img, 1 - self.opacity, 0, self.img)
        cv2.imwrite( self.saved_image, self.img)

        self.im = Image.open(self.saved_image)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)     

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent, width = 580, height = 360)         

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=tk.N+tk.W, image = self.photo)


def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

## Demo:

This is a screenshot of the running program:

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, and expands in what the first solution was getting at. However, I already have a lot built up around the GUI that uses the 'tkinter.label'. How can I do it using the label, as you mention is possible at the beginning of your solution?

Comment: If you want to use `tkinter.Label()` instead of `tkinter.Canvas()` then just rignore `self.canvas` in my code and create a label and append the image `self.photo` to it like this: `self.label = Tk.Label(self.parent, image = self.photo)` . And keep the rest of the code as it @DingoGetter

Comment: Also add this: `self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)`. The rest of the code remains as it is, just remove away `self.canvas` and create a new `Label()` as I explained.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  As stated in the title, I'm using Python 2.7 -- this is causing the above code to not run, so I'm trying to fix that. I don't suppose I could ask for a Python 2.7 version :D

Comment: The program remains the same in Python 2.7. Only one thing you have to change is :`import tkinter as tk` to `import Tkinter as Tk` @DingoGetter

Comment: Ah -- in that case, I have other dependencies that didn't match up. Regardless, I found a solution that better fit my case. I still used a canvas, but did not have to create a new class.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a canvas widget. That will allow you to draw an image, and then overlay a rectangle on it.

Answer (score 2):

Although the above answers were wonderfully in depth, they did not fit my exact situation (Specifically use of Python 2.7, etc.).  However, this solution gave me exactly what I was looking for:

```
canvas = Canvas(tab2, width=875, height=400)
image2=PhotoImage(file='lizard.gif')
canvas.create_image(440,180,image=image2)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)
```

The rectangle is added over the canvas using:

```
x1 = 3, y1 = 10, x2 = 30, y2 = 20
canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", stipple="gray12")
```

`stipple` comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465157/drawing-basic-shapes-in-python-2) example, to help add transparency to the rectangle.